# PHPStorm: How to POST XML to local PHP file

Tags: xml, post, phpstorm

I'm working on a PHP code using PHPStorm. I want to debug my script. My script reads an incoming XML string from the POST request body. How do I POST an XML doc to the script that is running locally on my computer?

Comment: For now I've added a simple check to see if script is running on server or on local computer. If local computer it reads the content of an xml file, if on server it reads the request body. Hoping there is a cleaner way.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "running locally": is it CLI environment (command line) or local web server ? If 2nd -- there is no difference; if 1st -- there is no GET/POST -- everything is passed as command line arguments